# iOS: Mute Toggle

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I am new to objective-c so please be easy. I have a game with sounds that play when the screen is tapped and when there is a collision. I would like to create a settings menu where it disables to sounds from playing.

`game.h`

```
SystemSoundID PlaySoundID;
SystemSoundID CrashSound;
```

`game.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"move" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL, &PlaySoundID);

NSURL *CrashSoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hit" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)CrashSoundURL, &CrashSound);
}
```

sound implementation example

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PlaySoundID);
}
```

In my `settings.m` I have attempted:

```
#import "GameViewController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

-(IBAction)muteButton:(id)sender {
[CrashSound stop];
}
```

But it is saying that there is a `use of an undeclared identifier 'CrashSound'`

Comment: Asking for general advise is not usually welcome here. Please show us what you have tried and what's not working.

Comment: Apologies I have made an edit with what I have attempted to do so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Multimedia Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW1),

> Sounds play at the current system audio volume, with no programmatic volume control available.

Perhaps it's better to use a sound framework where you can control the volume of each individual sound source. This way, you dont have to mess around with the device's volume settings (if it's even possible - I doubt it since the use would have control of the system volume) since the user may want the device's sound to be available for an alarm or a phone ring.

I recommend you use [this tutorial posted by 71 squared](http://vimeo.com/6440991) to create a singleton sound manager class based on OpenAL so that you can have on demand sound for your game as well as be able to control their sound volumes.